# How to upload a project to github in background

Tags: github

I tried `git push -u origin master &` and I get the question `Username for 'https://github.com':`. I enter my github userid but than the process terminates with:

```
MY_USER_ID: command not found.

[1]+  stopped              git push -u origin master
```

============= Solution ===================

Update .git/config from

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/YOURNAME/YOURPROJECT.git
    ...
```

to

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://USERID:PASSWORD@github.com/YOURNAME/YOURPROJECT.git
    ...
```

Another advantage in line mode is that one doesn't have to type in USERID and PASSWORD again and again.

Comment: before this did you do a `git remote add origin https://github.com/you_project_name.git` ?

Comment: Yes, I did the `add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this as well. I fixed it by editing `.git/config` using SSH and avoid HTTPS.

`git@github.com:Nature-Okoo/my_project.git`

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure if it is working. The job in the background is doing nothing. It works If I do it without `&` and with `https` in `.git/config`. But I would like to run it in background.

Comment: how about this other approach. Try edit your `.git/config` again . and change your` https://github.com/you_project_name.git` to  `https://*username*@github.com/you_project_name.git`. remember to save it and maybe do a `git pull` to test it.